# PHP object access array elements

Tags: php, arrays

I have this PHP object which I am trying to extract data from.

Object:

```
object(Symfony\Component\Test)#274 (2) {
  array(11) {
    ["objectclass"] array(4) {
      [0] "blue"
      [1] "yellow"
      [2] "red"
      [3] "green"
    }
    ["name"] array(1) {
      [0] "Bob"
    }
    ["surname"] array(1) {
      [0] "Peeterson"
    }
    ["title"] array(1) {
      [0] "Builder"
    }
    ["office"] array(1) {
      [0] "London-Branch"
    }
    ["givenname"] array(1) {
      [0] "Bob"
    }
    ["language"] array(1) {
      [0] "en-GB"
    }
    array(1) {
      [0] "565144652"
    }
    ["accounts"] array(2) {
      [0] "76474"
      [1] "16854"
    }
    array(1) {
      [0] "5"
    }
  }
}
```

So what I have here is a Object with 11 multidimensional arrays.  Now lets say now I only need to get all the elements from `objectclass array` && `name array` && `accounts array`

Ok so this is how i have tried to do this but get absolutely nothing:

OK so the object is stored in a var i.e:

```
$data = object();
foreach($data as $usr)
{
   var_dump($usr->objectclass);
}
```

Comment: `var_dump($usr['objectclass']);` should work. When in doubt use `echo '<pre>'.print_r($usr, true).'</pre>';` for a read-able representation of your object/array structure.

Comment: Array elements are access with `[]` and objects are accessed with `->`. They are not interchangeable like Javascript allows. If an object has a weird key like `my key` then `->{'my key'}` is needed.

Comment: Is `$data` multiple objects? it is unclear with what you have. The reason is you loop `$data` and either you are looping to get one of the many objects you have or you are looping an object getting each element in the object.

Comment: nop it s a single object as seen, I have tried all the suggestions no luck still, how can i get rid of the object and only keep the array wouldynt that be easier to iterate over...?

Comment: @nerdlyist I get this error: which seems very wired `Notice: Undefined property: Symfony\Component\Test::$objectclass`

Answer (score 0):

You are looping an object getting each of the elements on it. What would seem more appropriate is to just call what you want

```
$objectclass = $data->objectclass; //this is an array you can loop or access 
$objectclass[0]; //blue
```

Same for the other portion.

```
$name = $data->name[0]; //Bob
```

Of these you get arrays which you could loop

```
foreach ($objectclass as $oc){
    echo $oc;
}
```

output:

blue

yellow

red

green